# cut a string from position to another position

Tags: php, string, split

**Firstly**: I have the following string content

`Autumn, tree leafs<BR/><BR/><a title='Autumn, tree' href='http://site.net/share-picture/3K'><img width='225px' src='http://site.net/_s/upload/2013/11/29/0be99469a67aaf35b30b236e8ee9faa3.jpg225.jpg' title='Autumn, tree leafs' alt='Autumn, tree leafs'/></a><br/>`.

**Now**, what I want is cut part of that string, specifically `http://site.net/_s/upload/2013/11/29/0be99469a67aaf35b30b236e8ee9faa3.jpg225.jpg`, that affiliated to src tag.

**What I done is:**

```
function imgSrc($content){ 
    $srcPos = strpos($content, 'src');
    $srcCut = substr($content, $srcPos+5);

    return $srcCut;
}
```

The result of that function is `http://site.net/_s/upload/2013/11/29/0be99469a67aaf35b30b236e8ee9faa3.jpg225.jpg' title='Autumn, tree leafs and big clock' alt='Autumn, tree leafs and big clock'/>`.

But What I want is this only  `http://site.net/_s/upload/2013/11/29/0be99469a67aaf35b30b236e8ee9faa3.jpg225.jpg`.

Comment: Could you not just find the position of the next `' ` and use that for another substr call ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
echo rtrim(strstr($str," title",true),"'");
```

i.e.

```
function imgSrc($content){ 
    $srcPos = strpos($content, 'src');
    $srcCut = substr($content, $srcPos+5);
    $srcCut = rtrim(strstr($srcCut," title",true),"'"); //Added here

    return $srcCut;
}
```

Comment: Work fine thanks, but can you please explain this part `strstr($srcCut," title",true)`

Comment: `strstr()` returned the part of the haystack(your string) before the first occurrence of the needle since i had set the attribute to **true**

Comment: `" title"` is the needle which i had specified in the above comment and again the **true** is the attribute i had mentioned above again. You need to check the strstr documentation. http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php

Answer (score 0):

You should check out regex. Will always work :)

```
$string = "Autumn, tree leafs<BR/><BR/><a title='Autumn, tree' href='http://site.net/share-picture/3K'><img width='225px' src='http://site.net/_s/upload/2013/11/29/0be99469a67aaf35b30b236e8ee9faa3.jpg225.jpg' title='Autumn, tree leafs' alt='Autumn, tree leafs'/></a><br/>";

$count = preg_match_all('/src=(["\'])(.*?)\1/', $string, $match);
if ($count === FALSE) {
    print 'Nada\n';
} else { 
    print_r($match[2]);
}
```